# KiCAD: Footprint etc. for a breakout board on a PCB, which is to be designed

Tags: kicad

(I am no native English speaker....)
I am a very beginner to KiCAD (not to electronics, though) and want to design my first PCB with KiCAD (Linux): A Nixie clock.
To make my life a little more easier, I want to create a PCB, which mostly connects breakout boards of different parts of the Nixie clock together (Arduino Pro Mini, Nixie HV drivers, I2C expander etc.).
And here I got stuck: How can I create a "footprint" (?) and other things I need to have beforehand?
One solution I found was to use FreeCAD for this ... but some quirks in my system prevent to install FreeCAD successfully. And honestly...most of the parts of the solution I didn't understand.

Question remains: How can I create "footprints" for breakout boards easily?

Answer (score 2):

Kicad comes with an utility to design both schematics and footprints entries, the "PCB Footprint Editor". FreeCad would be useful to draw the 3D model of the components. Albeit useful and nice-looking, they are not mandatory in a design.

I can recommend this series on youtube as a good introduction to KiCad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHH4G_EWhm0. If you prefer something written (which can also be easily translated) I would advice this tutorial by SparkFun: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-kicad/creating-a-custom-kicad-footprint-library

Please note that Kicad itself also has a ton of resources on its website and the forum is very active. This is website for the official documentation: https://docs.kicad.org/, from where you can get the official getting started: https://docs.kicad.org/5.1/en/getting_started_in_kicad/getting_started_in_kicad.pdf

Comment: Which of the tons of resources directly answers my question?

Comment: All of them! It really boils down to your preference. Do you prefer following video tutorials? Go with the youtube video. Do you like to have a fast, but maybe not so thorough introduction to kicad? Go with the SparkFun one! Are you willing to explore kicad in all of its colours and shades? Then pick the extensive official docs.

Comment: My preference aside for the moment: What document contains the answer to my question?

Comment: I would go with the YT videos. They are nicely split in arguments, so you can follow the one related to footprints (the one I linked in the answer) step by step and solve your issue. Btw, I'm pretty sure the time took to reply to my question would have been better spent opening the links ;)